# Using Conditional Formatting With Words

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using a Spreadsheet in Google Docs, and trying to find a script that will let me do a kind of conditional formatting that Google will now allow on it's own.

If any cell in E has "Paid" in it I want the corresponding cell in G to turn green. So if E4 is paid, G4's background goes green. I know I need a script to do this, and I've tried looking through here, but I have 0 experience with scripts and have spent the last three days trying in vain to figure this out on my own.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? And, honestly, the dumber you assume I am, the better, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

[image: SO19759229 example]

(This is using New Google Sheets.)